# Thread getting stuck at ui4j.webkit.WebKitBrowser.navigate in linux

Tags: java, linux

I am using ui4j headless browser for my application.This is working in windows server. But when my server is getting deployed in linux, the thread is getting stuck while navigating the URL.

### Following is the stack trace of the thread

```
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=175 (Interpreted frame)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt() @bci=1, line=836 (Interpreted frame)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(int) @bci=72, line=997 (Interpreted frame)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(int) @bci=24, line=1304 (Compiled frame)
java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await() @bci=5, line=231 (Compiled frame)
com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.waitForStart() @bci=14, line=256 (Interpreted frame)
com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(java.lang.Runnable, boolean) @bci=26, line=277 (Interpreted frame)
com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(java.lang.Runnable) @bci=2, line=268 (Interpreted frame)
javafx.application.Platform.runLater(java.lang.Runnable) @bci=1, line=83 (Interpreted frame)
com.ui4j.webkit.WebKitBrowser.navigate(java.lang.String, com.ui4j.api.browser.PageConfiguration) @bci=250, line=382 (Interpreted frame)
```

### com.ui4j.webkit.WebKitBrowser.navigate(java.lang.String) @bci=9, line=341 (Interpreted frame)

The URL i am trying to navigate is opening if I open the same outside.

I am using ui4j-all-2.1.0.jar.

Comment: add 4 spaces in fron t of each line in stack trace to improve readability please.

Comment: I am still facing issue while navigating a simple jsp page using ui4j. The thread is getting stuck.